# Numerical modelling of a step function in time in a hydrodynamic system. (Runge Kutta fourth order)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, differential-equations, numerical-method

So I'm trying to model a hydrodynamic system that introduces a sudden "jump" in the value of a function at a specific time. The system is solved with a Runge-Kutta fourth order method.

I have a hydrodynamic system where there is a phase transition modelled by a sudden increase in pressure that I'm modelling with a heavyside function. The problem is that this step-function introduces a lot of stiffness.

In other words, after temperature is less than T, pressure goes from

$P→P+A$

where $A$ is the extra factor that suddenly increases the pressure.

I was wondering if it's possible to "approximate" the step-function as a linear function into a continous function to reduce the stiffness. I was thinking of multiplying A by a linear function that increases linearly with time until the linear function reaches 1.

Comment: Though exponential & not linear, [hyperbolic tangents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) can work fairly well as a rather simplistic model of the step function.

Comment: Yes. I've tried that before, hehe. But the thing is that the solution seems to become stable until I choose a very smooth function, which I'm not comfortable with because the timescale of the phase transition becomes too large. Otherwise, at smaller timescales the solution becomes unstable at the time where the slope of the tanh curve becomes the steepest.

Comment: That's why I was thinking of using a linear function because then the curve  has a constant slope. Therefore I don't have the problem where the solution is "stable" at the parts of the tanh that are the less steep only to become unstable in the steep part.

Comment: If I recall "stiffness" is a property of the equations, not a property of the stimuli. Your solver is probably just borderline stable at any time, which you won't notice because the numerical errors don't add up to enough noise to make your life miserable. Add noise to the problem and see what your solver does with it in the frequency domain. If that doesn't look good, then trying to solve a problem with a large jump won't do any good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it that way.

You have what is called a "Change Point".

Run it up until the time when the change should occur.
Then stop the solver.
Perform the instantaneous state change.
Then restart the solver.

So much silliness happens when people try to run ODE solvers over discontinuities.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I read more about this "Change points".?

Comment: It's not a deep concept. It happens all the time in pharmacometric modeling, like [*here*](http://www.cognigencorp.com/nonmem/nm/98oct061998.html). [*Here's*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3636497/) something that may be a bit much. Basically, any pharmacometric model expressed as a set of differential equations has to receive doses at points in time. So the ODE solver runs up to that time and stops. Then the dose is given which, for example, bumps the amount of drug in blood plasma. Then the ODE solver is started up again, up to the next event time, like an observation.

Comment: This is good advice. While there is no such thing as "instantaneous", the discontinuity you introduce may not be worth resolving / investigating. If it is, you need to make it smooth up to the scale of interest (a bit like filtering the input of a ADC to stay below Nyquist). But if you are not interested you should avoid solving across that point.

Comment: @Floris: The models we make are always idealized at some level - we take that as a given. Since we're trying to fit a model to rather sparse data, we have to keep the model simple enough that the data can say something about it, so the exact mechanism for things that take almost no time is pedantic.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I don't disagree - but it does depend on the situation. Sometimes you want to study the details of a transition - but if you start out with sparse data I agree it is a fool's errand to over analyze.

Answer (score 0):

RK 4th order is a good numerical approach - but it is only accurate up to fourth order terms in the Taylor expansion of your series.  As long as the fifth (and higher) order derivatives of the function are small, you are fine. But when you introduce a step function, or even a piecewise linear approximation, that assumption is violated.

I would recommend, as Kyle Kanos suggested in his comment, to find a suitable smooth function (the hyperbolic tangent works well with the right scaling) in order to turn your sudden transition into a smooth one. If that doesn't result in a stable solution, you are doing something wrong (hard to guess what - but it *should* be stable as you decrease the step size).

As an aside, even phase transitions tend not to happen "all at once" but somewhat gradually - so a smoothly varying function isn't such a bad thing to use in your simulation.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll keep testing tanh and see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your time step has to be short compared to the range over which the derivatives change. How does the instability manifest itself?

Comment: I think I was having really long timescales because I was scaling the hyperbolic tanh so that it changes much slowly as opposed to lowering the timestep. I'm going to now lower the timestep. Thanks!

Comment: @mathdummy let us know how it works out!

Comment: It worked! Kinda. But now I have really strong pressure gradient between the part of the fluid that had a phase transition and the part that didnt,and it doesn't really "dampen". I suspect it's because I need a finer grid to resolve the gradient. So I'm gonna keep trucking. But seems that adding a hyperbolic function in general works for this sort of problems.